# Implementing something like Google Calendar or Google Sheet in Android

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I have been facing this problem for days and havn't sorted this out.  I want to implement something like the calendar app where we have

1)Two way scrolling (vertical and horizontal)
2)Sticky Header and sticky Column (so first column and first row sticks)

I am using a recycler view and wondering would using these library work?

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/
https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

I am really stuck and hope someone can point me to the right direction!

Thank you